# MediaStore Thumbnail images looks blurry

Tags: android, gridview, android-image, android-gallery

I am trying to fetch the images and display in Grid,it works good but the images looks blurry.

Below is what i have tried :(In descending order)

```
final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = cursor.getCount();
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        ids = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            ids[i] = cursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            arrPath[i] = cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
```

Please help me to correct code.

Comment: how are you generating the bitmap ? can you update your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) library. It is so simple. Just add library dependency to your project and then put below lines to your class. Your adapter is ready, you can set it for your gridview.

```
RecentImages ri = new RecentImages();
ImageAdapter adapter = ri.getAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

It has some option for customizing your query on images.

Comment: I found a bug that in the above library, the images gets skewed in the grid, do you know any other library which does the similar job?

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.